How to convert a segmented 3D image into a FE mesh with different sub-regions?
I am exploring how to use Mathematica to segment micro - CT images into multiple regions and in the next step use this segmentation to create a water-tight finite element mesh which can then be used for FE simulations. This can be done in 3D imaging software such as Amira or Dragonfly, it would be useful to be able to do this inside of Mathematica.
The real problem is to create a mesh from  the segmented 3D image which has multiple regions. Ideally we would like these multiple regions to be directly separated by internal boundaries so we can apply different material properties etc. The built in function ImageMesh[] only gives the surface of the (3D) image and ignores any internal boundaries (it seems to consider the 3D image as a binary image).
As a typical µCT data sets can be enormous. we try with the following contrived problem. Consider the following 3D data set containing two different regions.
dataset = Table[If[RegionMember[Ball[{25, 25, 25}, 10], {i, j, k}], 1, If[RegionMember[Cuboid[{10, 10, 10}, {40, 40, 25}], {i, j, k}], 2, 0]], {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}, {k, 1, 50}];
Image3D[dataset]
dataset[[All, All, 20]] // ArrayPlot

This gives the following:

or in a given slice we have:

If we calculate the mesh of this Image we get:
mesh = ImageMesh[Image3D[dataset], Method -> "MarchingCubes"]
Show[mesh, PlotRange -> {All, {25, 50}, All}]


if we look at the inside of the mesh there is no internal boundary

Here we are missing the internal boundary which would enable us to create different material properties mesh refinement etc...
How can we create meshes with internal boundaries from such data sets using mathematica?
A first attempt is the following:
I have found one way of doing this, but not too sure whether it will always work. It seems that the boundaries of the marching cube algorithm for the separate regions match reasonably well meaning the regions may be able to be meshed separately and then merged. This may not be robust and I haven't tested extensively yet, but thought I could give this answer as a start.
We need to load the FE and OpenCascade Packages.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]

We first create two separate data sets for each material and calculate separate meshes for each using the Marching Cubes algorithm.
material1 = Threshold[dataset, 1];
material2 = dataset - material1;
mesh1 = ImageMesh[Image3D[material1], Method -> "MarchingCubes"]
mesh2 = ImageMesh[Image3D[material2], Method -> "MarchingCubes"]



We then convert these into boundary meshes and import into Open Cascade format, find their union and intersection and join these together to create the internal boundaries.
bm1 = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh1];
bm2 = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh2];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[bm1];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[bm2];
union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[shape1, shape2];
intersection = OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[union, shape2];
shape = OpenCascadeShapeSewing[{union, intersection}];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
bmesh["Wireframe"]

We then get a mesh which has an internal boundary.

Unfortunately upon trying to create a full 3D mesh with different regions Mathematica crashes.
emesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> {{{11, 11, 11}, 1}, {{25, 25, 25}, 2}}]

Any ideas how to solve this?

@user21 thanks yes that is correct.

This is, I think, a tricky problem in general. Here is a workflow, that I hope works reasonably well, also beyond this example.
Create the test data:
dataset = 
  Table[If[RegionMember[Ball[{25, 25, 25}, 10], {i, j, k}], 1, 
    If[RegionMember[Cuboid[{10, 10, 10}, {40, 40, 25}], {i, j, k}], 2,
      0]], {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}, {k, 1, 50}];
(*Image3D[dataset]*)
(*dataset[[All,All,20]]//ArrayPlot*)
material1 = Threshold[dataset, 1];
material2 = dataset - material1;

I think it is vital the the ImageMesh results return the same thing for each part. While I have not tried other methods I started with the "Exact" method:
mo = "Exact";
(*mo="MarchingCubes";*)
(*mo="DualMarchingCubes";*)
mesh1 = ImageMesh[Image3D[material1], Method -> mo];
mesh2 = ImageMesh[Image3D[material2], Method -> mo];

The difference to your approach is that I look at the faces and have OpenCascadeShapeUnion create the union of the faces. This is an expensive operation, but should be quite robust.
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
bm1 = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh1];
bm2 = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh2];
shape1 = OpenCascadeShape[bm1];
shape2 = OpenCascadeShape[bm2];
faces1 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape1];
faces2 = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[shape2];

Length /@ {faces1, faces2}
AbsoluteTiming[
 union = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[Flatten[{faces1, faces2}]];]

(* {1172, 2100}

{188.597, Null} *)

It takes 3 minutes for this example. If you do not have too many faces in your actual data, this might be workable.
shape = OpenCascadeShapeSimplify[union];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
bmesh["Wireframe"]

Not sure if the shape simplify is really necessary.

emesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{11, 11, 11}, 1}, {{25, 25, 25}, 2}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]

parts = Map[
  emesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == #[[1]], 
     "MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#[[2]]]]]] &, {{1, Gray}, {2, 
    Orange}}]


Show[parts, PlotRange -> {All, {25, 41}, All}]



This is great. I think it is also not easy, I will have to try reading up a bit more about how 3D image analysis software manages this. I have seen that there are multi-region marching cube algorithms around, but not too sure how easy they are to implement.
